# iOS Navigation controller navigation items disappear

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

Im trying to use the NavigationController i a simple iPhone app, on some of the views i want to hide the back button, this is working fine with the following code in the View view controller

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    //Hide back button
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true;
}
```

My storyboard setup is like this: http://i39.tinypic.com/24y013p.png

The app is working fine on the emulator, but the navigation items is not displayed in XCode, but if i select the navigation controller, they are displayed again, they disappear again as soon as i select any of the views. If i remove the seque from View3 to View1 the navigation items is displaying fine again.

Whats wrong?

Comment: 1) What does this have to do with `xcode`? **Nothing** 2) Why the question title `Load JavaScript dynamically`? What in this fine earth does this have to do with `Javascript`? There is no reference to any `javascript` in this question.

Comment: i Know, its from another post. Stackoverflow remembered my last post. Sorry

Comment: This is nothing to do with `xcode` just because you are using the `xcode IDE` does not mean this is an `xcode` issue. The `xcode` tag is reserved for issues relating to the `xcode IDE` itself such as "Why doesn't xcode open?". So please do not re-tag with the `xcode` tag.

Comment: If its a Xcode bug, it has something to do with XCode.

Comment: This is not an `xcode` bug. From what you have explain this has nothing to do with `xcode` at all. If you have failed to provide all the information that may indicate that this is an `xcode` bug then please share, but at present this has nothing to do with `xcode` so please stop using that tag.